# Threadsafe function pointer with Rcpp and RcppParallel via std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, rcpp, rcppparallel

I would like to use a threadsafe function pointer to be applied in an RcppPrallel worker. But I have already problems with this tiny example. No matter if I use it in a package and add `SystemRequirements: C++11` in the DESCRIPTION file, or use it in a standard cpp file and add `// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]` I get the same **Errors: 'shared_ptr' is not a member of 'std'**. Can anyone please help me? Thank you!

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;


double f1 (double x, double y) {
   return x * y;
}

double f2 (double x, double y) {
   std::shared_ptr<int> p1;
   std::cout << "p1: " << p1.use_count() << '\n';
   return x + y;
}

typedef double (*funcPtr)(double x, double y);

std::shared_ptr<funcPtr> selectf(std::string abc) {

   std::shared_ptr<funcPtr> fp = NULL;

   if(abc == "a"){
      fp = std::make_shared<funcPtr>(new funcPtr(&f1));
   }else {
      fp = std::make_shared<funcPtr>(new funcPtr(&f2));
   }
   return fp;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
double f0(double x, double y, std::string abc){
   double ret;
   df = selectf(abc);
   ret = df(x, y);
   return(ret);
}


/*** R
if(FALSE){
   f0(10, 10, "a")
}
*/
```

System information:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.5.0  R6_2.2.2        magrittr_1.5   
 [4] tools_3.5.0     withr_2.1.2     roxygen2_6.0.1 
 [7] yaml_2.1.19     memoise_1.1.0   Rcpp_0.12.18   
[10] xml2_1.2.0      stringi_1.2.2   stringr_1.3.1  
[13] digest_0.6.15   commonmark_1.5  devtools_1.13.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` is declared in the header `<memory>`. Try:

```
#include <memory>
```

You can find the documentation for it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: Thanks. I tried it before, but when I use `#include <memory>` and `// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]] ` at the same time in the header of the file my R session crashes with no further error message

Comment: Well that is different problem then. I see other errors in your code (no declaration for `df`), and maybe your use of function pointer is incorrect...

Comment: Thank you! I also tried the toy example from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/) and added `// [[Rcpp::export]]` to export the `main`, and had the same issues with R crashes. I use Rstudio 1.1.453.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer already told you about `#include <memory>`; in the follow-up you claim the basic example does not work -- it does for me.

But one clarification first:  *all* memory management across calls to added (compiled) functions has to happen via R's memory management. That is what Rcpp does, and what Rcpp documents.  Now, for multithreaded code we have `RMatrix` and `RVector` in RcppParalllel because we *cannot* interfere with R's memory management (and its single-threaded mode) from multithreaded code; see RcppParallel's excellent documentation for details.

That said, if you are sure you want `shared_ptr` within defined scope, you can.  Here is a working copy based on the example you linked too.

#### Code

```
#include <memory>
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

struct C { int* data; };

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool foo() {
   std::shared_ptr<int> p1;
   std::shared_ptr<int> p2 (nullptr);
   std::shared_ptr<int> p3 (new int);
   std::shared_ptr<int> p4 (new int, std::default_delete<int>());
   std::shared_ptr<int> p5 (new int, [](int* p){delete p;}, std::allocator<int>());
   std::shared_ptr<int> p6 (p5);
   std::shared_ptr<int> p7 (std::move(p6));
   std::shared_ptr<int> p8 (std::unique_ptr<int>(new int));
   std::shared_ptr<C> obj (new C);
   std::shared_ptr<int> p9 (obj, obj->data);

   Rcpp::Rcout << "use_count:\n";
   Rcpp::Rcout << "p1: " << p1.use_count() << '\n';
   Rcpp::Rcout << "p2: " << p2.use_count() << '\n';
   Rcpp::Rcout << "p3: " << p3.use_count() << '\n';
   Rcpp::Rcout << "p4: " << p4.use_count() << '\n';
   Rcpp::Rcout << "p5: " << p5.use_count() << '\n';
   Rcpp::Rcout << "p6: " << p6.use_count() << '\n';
   Rcpp::Rcout << "p7: " << p7.use_count() << '\n';
   Rcpp::Rcout << "p8: " << p8.use_count() << '\n';
   Rcpp::Rcout << "p9: " << p9.use_count() << '\n';

   return true;
}
```

#### Use

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("/tmp/soExample.cpp")
R> foo()
use_count:
p1: 0
p2: 0
p3: 1
p4: 1
p5: 2
p6: 0
p7: 2
p8: 1
p9: 2
[1] TRUE
R>
```

Comment: Thank you! Now the toy example works for me as well. I thought a shared pointer is exactly what I need for defining function pointers pointing all to the same function for each worker of a multithreaded process. I could not find an exampe in the Rcpp gallery where a fucntion pointer is passed to a worker. Would this be possibe or impossible due to your explanation above? Thank you.

Comment: Well you only wrote it did _not_ work for you so your writeup was incompleye and made other people (ie me) waste their time.  Lesson: Write more complete and informative posts here.  Lastly, there is a reason `shared_ptr` is not in the Rcpp Gallery, and that reason in my second paragraph above, and in the Writing R Extensions manual.  It cannot work as you have to work primarily with R's memory management (where we use a different reference count).

Comment: Thank you for your help.