# std::mt19937 in Rcpp

Tags: c++, std, rcpp, rcppparallel

This problem arose from testing my R (RcppParallel) package on windows through the win-builder-r, as for my mac there is not a problem.

`"error: 'mt19937' is not a member of 'std'"`

Additionally, this error comes first:

> D:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

A minimal example can be found from this earlier post, use the last : [Calling 'mypackage' function within public worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51976337/calling-mypackage-function-within-public-worker)

Comment: *Read* the error message. It tels you *exactly* what to do.

Comment: Follow this guide from MS for setting compiler options https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/blob/master/docs/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version.md

Comment: How are you compiling this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<random>`header in general and [`std::mt19337`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) in particular are only available with C++11 and later. And if you want to use C++11 on Windows in the context of an R package, you are supposed to add

```
CXX_STD = CXX11
```

to `src/Makevars.win` (Source: [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-C_002b_002b11-code)). On other platforms one often gets by without this, since there newer compilers are used that use C++11 by default. However, please note that WRE discourages the usage of `random` from C++11, probably because the distribution functions are implementation defined.