# Parallel Worker in namespace

Tags: r, rcpp, rcppparallel, rcpparmadillo

This example is a follow up example from this earlier post.  I am trying to move the Parallel Worker to its own cpp file and and declare it in the header file.

[Calling 'mypackage' function within public worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51976337/calling-mypackage-function-within-public-worker)

The two errors are as follows:
1) variable type 'ExampleInternal::PARALLEL_WORKER' is an abstract class

and in my non-reproducible example:
2) error: expected unqualified-id on the 'ExampleInternal::PARALLEL_WORKER{' line in the Parallel_worker.cpp file.

Right now the code looks like this:

ExampleInternal.h

```
#ifndef ExampleInternal_H
#define ExampleInternal_H

namespace ExampleInternal{

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppParallel.h>

double myfunc3(arma::vec vec_in){

  int Len = arma::size(vec_in)[0];
  return (vec_in[0] +vec_in[1])/Len;
}

struct PARALLEL_WORKER : RcppParallel::Worker{};

}


#endif
```

Parallel_Worker.cpp

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppParallel.h>
#include <random>
#include "ExampleInternal.h"

using namespace RcppParallel;
using namespace ExampleInternal;

namespace ExampleInternal{

ExampleInternal::PARALLEL_WORKER{

  const arma::vec &input;
  arma::vec &output;

  PARALLEL_WORKER(const arma::vec &input, arma::vec &output) : input(input), output(output) {}

  void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end){


    std::mt19937 engine(1);

    // Create a loop that runs through a selected section of the total Boot_reps
    for( int k = begin; k < end; k ++){
      engine.seed(k);
      arma::vec index = input;
      std::shuffle( index.begin(), index.end(), engine);

      output[k] = ExampleInternal::myfunc3(index);
    }
  }

};

} //Close Namespace
```

Parallel_func.cpp

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppParallel.h>
#include "ExampleInternal.h"
using namespace ExampleInternal;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec Parallelfunc(int Len_in){

  arma::vec input = arma::regspace(0, 500);
  arma::vec output(Len_in);

  ExampleInternal::PARALLEL_WORKER parallel_woker(input, output);
  parallelFor( 0, Len_in, parallel_woker);
  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the split between the declaration and the definition of your struct correctly. The declaration in the header file contains the member variables and method signatures.

```cpp
namespace ExampleInternal{

struct PARALLEL_WORKER : RcppParallel::Worker{
  const arma::vec &input;
  arma::vec &output;

  PARALLEL_WORKER(const arma::vec &input, arma::vec &output);
  void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end);

};
}
```

In the cpp file you then define your methods:

```cpp
namespace ExampleInternal{

  PARALLEL_WORKER::PARALLEL_WORKER(const arma::vec &input, arma::vec &output) : input(input), output(output) {}

  void PARALLEL_WORKER::operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end){

    std::mt19937 engine(1);

    // Create a loop that runs through a selected section of the total Boot_reps
    for( std::size_t k = begin; k < end; k ++){
      engine.seed(k);
      arma::vec index = input;
      std::shuffle( index.begin(), index.end(), engine);

      output[k] = ExampleInternal::myfunc3(index);
    }
  }


} //Close Namespace
```

I had to do a few more changes to get everything compiled without warnings (the function defined in the header should be `inline` etc.) Full details at https://github.com/rstub/stackoverflow/tree/master/55082456. Note that some of the changes make only sense in the context of Rcpp Attributes *outside* of a package.
BTW, since you don't provide test data, I have only verified the compilation, not proper operation.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a follow up.  To move myfunc3 to a separate .cpp file required me to include the RcppParallel header to the myfunc3.cpp file. I also didn't have to add the 'inline'.

myfunc3.cpp

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppParallel.h>
#include "ExampleInternal.h"

using namespace arma;

namespace ExampleInternal{

double myfunc3(arma::vec vec_in){

  int Len = arma::size(vec_in)[0];
  return (vec_in[0] +vec_in[1])/Len;
}

} // Close namespace
```

and the ExampleInternal.h

```
#ifndef ExampleInternal_H
#define ExampleInternal_H

namespace ExampleInternal{

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppParallel.h>

double myfunc3(arma::vec vec_in);

struct PARALLEL_WORKER : RcppParallel::Worker{
  const arma::vec &input;
  arma::vec &output;
  PARALLEL_WORKER( const arma::vec &input, arma::vec &output);
  void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end);
};

}

#endif
```